# Big O Notation and negative "n"

Tags: notation, asymptotics

So I'm studying big $O$ notation right now and am working through a problem and got  $O(x^{-10})$ and I'm just wondering if it's possible to even have a term with $O(x^{-n})$ because I've never come across it any of the examples we've gone through in class.

Thanks!

Comment: Theoretically it's possible, but such a program would go faster with larger inputs and in practice such programs are rare (and for such a large value of $n$ pretty much unheard of, at least to my knowledge).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, but it's not typical in either the computer science setting (where the notation is used to describe runtime as a function of input size) or the analysis setting (where the notation is used to describe the error in a local approximation of a function near a point).

Comment: In many subareas of computer science, the running time can depend on several inputs, some of them going to $0$. One usual example would be [approximation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm), where a [PTAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) has running time dependeing on input size $n$ and error guarantee $\varepsilon$, the latter "going to 0."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the comments, the sensibleness of such an outcome depends on context. As in the comments, this would not be a sensible answer to a question of run-time on input size $x$. It is also not so likely to be a helpful answer if $f(x)=O(x^{-1})$ as $|x|\to 0$. But it *might* be a sensible answer as part of an asymptotic expansion of a function as $|x|\to \infty$. For example, with $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$, as $|x|\to\infty$ $|f(x)|=O(x^{-2})$.

Comment: As a followup comment, nothing in the definition of $O(\cdot)$ makes it specific to inputs going to infinity, even in computer science: examples could be approximation algorithms, property testing, or differential privacy, where the time (or sample) complexity depends on a parameter $\varepsilon$  going to $0$. Then, complexities of the sort $O(\varepsilon^{-2})$ are quite common.